# PHP parsing portions of mysql result as variable on preg_replace

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, preg-replace

I have some flags I store in my mysql database so I can dynamically generate links and title tags using the following code; however, it seems to parse anything with a dollar sign as a variable.

```
foreach($result as $value){
    $id = $value['id'];
    $title = $value['title'];
    $synopsis = $value['synopsis'];

    $synopsis = preg_replace('/<!--TITLE-->/', $title, $synopsis);
}
```

So if the title is "$500,000 donated to blah blah" it will output "0,000 donated to blah blah". How can I make it not parse this out? I'm not able to store the ascii value `&#36;` in the database for this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_replace` looks through the second string and if it sees a $, treats it and the digits that follow as a reference to the capture group with that number.  (It only takes the first two digits, though; the number ranges from 0 to 99.)   And since you don't have a 50th capture group, it interprets the `$50` as nothing.

If you're just looking to find and replace a known string rather than a pattern, try using `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace`.  It doesn't have such gotchas.

Answer (score 1):

$ sign in preg_replace determines parentheses in regular expressions. Then $50 means 50'th parenthes in $pattern. It is similar to \50 at preg_replace. see http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Please try

```
foreach($result as $value){
    $id = $value['id'];
    $title = preg_replace('@\\\\(\d+)@' ,'\\\\\\\\$1', preg_replace("/\\$/","&#36;",$value['title']));      
   $synopsis = $value['synopsis'];
    $synopsis = preg_replace('/<!--TITLE-->/', $title, $synopsis);
}
```

Comment: And why would that work?  An answer needs a bit more than just "here, copy/paste this", or it doesn't help anyone learn.

Comment: That does indeed work; however, I was hoping there was some function or something in PHP which would make it not parse these things as variables. A find replace on a dollar sign seems a bit hack and slash.

Comment: sure @cHao . I edit my answer with compelmantry descriptions.

Comment: @patrick-robert-shea-oconnor this trick is very intresting case. also you must repalce \\ in title too. because \\500 returns 500th parenthes . very intresting case you found. Thanks.